# Is there a programmatic way to extract the data from "paint profiler" in the Devtools Performance tab from Puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I was wondering if there was a way to get the data from the "Paint Profiler" via Puppeteer? I have posted a screenshot at the bottom of this post. Ideally, I would like it to be in JSON format, but I'll take anything I can get.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[`LayerTree.PaintProfile`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/LayerTree/#type-PaintProfile) is available via the Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP), but I don't see it exposed when searching [Puppeteer's API](https://pptr.dev/). Puppeteer's [`CDPSession`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.0.0&show=api-class-cdpsession) should provide the low-level JSON access non-exposed CDP features like `LayerTree.PaintProfile`.

Comment: LayerTree is definitely a good start. I looked through the documentation. What I specifically want is the "LayerTree.PictureTile" object. However, I can't seem to find a method to get it. Any advice?

Comment: It's worth reaching out to [@ChromeDevTools](https://twitter.com/ChromeDevTools). They're great and may be able to assist.